# docker > run two nodejs scripts using gulp and nodemon

Tags: node.js, docker, gulp, nodemon

I'm trying whole day to find some solution how to run two scripts written in nodejs parallel in docker.

I've two files:
app/index.js - express app using port 8080
app/rabbit.js - script is connection to rabbitmq only as consumer and processing messages

I'm trying to use gulp and nodemon ( I've found solution on the stackoverflow, but id doesn't work )

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var gulputil = require('gulp-util');
var child_process = require('child_process');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');

var processes = {server1: null, server2: null};

gulp.task('start:server', function (cb) {

processes.server1 = nodemon({
    script: "app/index.js",
    ext: "js"
});

processes.server2 = nodemon({
    script: "app/rabbit.js",
    ext: "js"
});

cb(); // For parallel execution accept a callback.
      // For further info see "Async task support" section here:
      // https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md
});

process.on('exit', function () {
 // In case the gulp process is closed (e.g. by pressing [CTRL + C]) stop    both processes
processes.server1.kill();
processes.server2.kill();
});

gulp.task('run', ['start:server']);
gulp.task('default', ['run']);
```

This is always runs second script "app/rabbit.js" twice. I'm open to any solution, but I need to run two nodejs script at once in one docker instance.

Any Ideas? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who will have same problem, I've found solution.

Step 1:

```
Create two docker files Dockerfile-api, Dockerfile-messages
As command RUN in the dockerfile use
  a. CMD ["npm", "run", "start-api"]
  b. CMD ["npm", "run", "start-messages"]
```

Step 2:

```
In the package.json add lines:
 "scripts": {     
   "start-api": "gulp --gulpfile app/gulpfile-api.js",
   "start-messages": "gulp --gulpfile app/gulpfile-messages.js"
  }
```

Step 3:

```
Obviously create two gulp files, each gulp file will have his own script.
```

Step 4:

```
Create two services in docker-compose.yml file each witch different DockerFile
```

Step 5:

```
Run docker-compose up
```